# Richtext field causing DominoDocument.setValue() error

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

Recently while using richtext field and ckeditor I started receiving following error while trying to run any kind of action that submits richtext value:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Notes exception thrown while calling DominoDocument.setValue() on field rt
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.setValue(DominoDocument.java:1465)
at com.ibm.xsp.el.PropertyResolverImpl.setValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:206)
at com.sun.faces.el.impl.ArraySuffix.setValue(ArraySuffix.java:201)
at com.sun.faces.el.impl.ComplexValue.setValue(ComplexValue.java:180)
at com.sun.faces.el.ValueBindingImpl.setValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:206)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIInputEx.updateModel(UIInputEx.java:573)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:484)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processUpdates(UIDataPanelBase.java:351)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processUpdates(UIDataPanelBase.java:351)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processUpdates(UIDataPanelBase.java:351)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processUpdates(UIDataPanelBase.java:351)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processUpdates(UIDataPanelBase.java:351)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processUpdates(UIDataPanelBase.java:351)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processUpdates(UIDataPanelBase.java:351)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:222)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:406)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._processUpdates(UIViewRootEx.java:1513)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.processUpdates(UIViewRootEx.java:1492)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:223)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

Caused by: NotesException: Note item not found
at lotus.domino.local.Document.closeMIMEEntities(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.closeMIMEEntities(DominoRichTextItem.java:2531)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.getRichTextField(DominoDocument.java:1979)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.createRTFieldWithValue(DominoDocument.java:1998)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.setValue(DominoDocument.java:1382)
... 60 more
```

Anybody know what could possibly cause this kind of behaviour? I've got quite complex design with excesive use of extension library and this error appeared out of nowhere at some point. I cannot pin point what caused it because it was partially obscured by my logging code which unnecessarly called DominoDocument.getDocument(true).

After removing this call this error started to appear. Adding arbitral call DominoDocument.getDocument(true) to random 'rendered' attribute ssjs code seems to partially solve this problem (this is where the logging code was in the first place).

But still this is hack and I would like to know what went wrong in the begining.

This seems to be somehow connected to state of FieldValueHolder of DominoRichTextItem (its operation fields is set to REPLACE instead to ADD !?)

Can anybody help ?

Comment: `Caused by: NotesException: Note item not found` - what item are you accessing?

Comment: Its not me - its the xpages logic that is trying to close MIME entity. I only do partial refresh on the area around rich text.

Comment: What code is calling "DominoDocument.setValue() on field rt"? This code must take into consideration that DominoDocument might not exist.

Comment: The code odf PropertyResolverImpl. Its part of xpages logic. This happens when data is submitted to server (for example when partial update is done). This is code that I do not control. I suppose this error is only side effect of something I have done during document initialization. But I still cannot locate the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the root of the problem. I appears that if You remove formName attribute from document data source the side effect is this exception and disappearing attachments.

This regression was introducted to my application while adding some document response functionality (the form was computed in events so somebody threw away formName attribute). And what is worse the problem with attachments was obscured by some getDocument(true) call in debug code.

It would be nice if xsp compiler mentioned that formName is obligatory attribute ...

Comment: Thanks, was getting inconsistent errors because of this, your recommendation solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If your calling REPLACE on a document that doesn't exist you would be getting an error and given it occurs after you removed the code to check whether to rendering it or not, really sounds as though the issue is the document doesn't exist.

Have you checked this out? also the easiest way to use a rich text item is just to bind it to a field

```
e.g.  value="#{dominoDoc.body}"
```

This might not always be possible but it gets over issues like this where custom code causes errors.

Comment: The field is binded like in your example. The document should not exist because this is a new document :). And this error only happens if richtext is present. If i will change richtext to normal edit box everything works fine.

Comment: Everything should also be fine when you save the document with an empty rich text field first, and then you edit it.

Comment: After 2 days debugging... It all came back to me after reading your line about "new document".

Comment: @D.Bugger: And did You find the reason behind this behaviour or at least any feasible solution ?

Comment: Create a new document using back-end objects, set some status field to "Empty", save the document, then open or edit it using its NoteId. The status field can be used to hide abandoned new documents from views and/or to delete them in an agent.